# AES 128 CBC: How to calculate correct IV?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

```
<?php

$data = '
    -What is the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything ?
    -42
';
$method = 'AES-128-CBC';
$password = 'secret password';
$raw_output = $raw_input = true;

$iv_len = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_len);

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $password, $raw_output, $iv);
var_dump($encrypted);


echo 'Decryption with known IV: OK';
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $password, $raw_input, $iv);
var_dump($decrypted);

echo 'Decryption with calculated IV: Fail<br><br>';
$iv = substr($encrypted, 0, $iv_len);
echo 'Without substring';
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $password, $raw_input, $iv);
var_dump($decrypted);
echo 'With substring';
$encrypted = substr($encrypted, $iv_len);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $password, $raw_input, $iv);
var_dump($decrypted);
```

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are assuming that the first 16 bytes in the encrypted string are the IV. Is there any reason to assume that? The IV is part of the key, and you cannot calculate it from the encrypted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are assuming that your IV is at the beginning of the encrypted output but your are not explicitly putting it there.

Try:

```
$encrypted = $iv . openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $password, $raw_output, $iv);
```

and try decrypting with:

```
$iv = substr($encrypted, 0, $iv_len);
$encrypted = substr($encrypted, $iv_len);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $password, $raw_input, $iv);
var_dump($decrypted);
```